# How do I read the connectstring from asp.net 5 project

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac

I have a asp.net 5 web application with an appsettings.json file.  My data access layer is the old 4.5.1 project style with an app.config, using EF 6.

How can I get the connectString from my asp.net 5 applicaiton.json to the DbContext class in the old style?

Here is what I am currently trying:

My DbContext class takes an IDbConnectString parameter in it's constructor.

In startup (of the asp.net 5 project) I load my connect string class from appsettings.json with this:

```
 services.Configure<Models.Security.MyConnectString>(Configuration.GetSection("Data:MyConnection"));
```

This creates allows the injection of an IOptions object with the type MyConnectString.  However, the DAL project has no reference to IOptions (it's not asp.net 5).

Then I setup dependency injection with this:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyConnectString, Models.Security.MyConnectString>
```

When the MyConnection class is injected, it's a new class - not the one I loaded from appsettings.

Any advice on how to do this?

I am also using AutoFac dependency injection.  It has the ability set the return valueof a property like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyConnectString>()
            .As<IMyConnectString>()
            .WithProperty("ConnectionString", "--- what goes here ---");
```

I set this up in the ASP.net 5 project.  If I could get an instance of the MyConnectString class with the appsettings.data (from startup) I could use it here.